# How to delete row with past date and add this row to an other table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Please help. I have 2 tables. First one is called Reservation and second one is called LastOrders.

There are the columns DATE_FROM in Date type and DATE:)_TO in date type too. And I want if the date in table Reservation in column DATE_TO = SYSDATE then delete this row and insert new row to table LastOrders I think a trigger can do that, but I dont know how. Any idea? Thank you very much and have a nice Christmas :)

```
TABLE RESERVATION
Name                       Null     Type          
-------------------------- -------- ------------- 
ID                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)  
DESCRIPTION                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)      
DATE_FROM                  NOT NULL DATE          
DATE_TO                    NOT NULL DATE  

TABLE LASTORDERS
Name                       Null     Type          
-------------------------- -------- ------------- 
ID                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)  
DESCRIPTION                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)      
DATE_FROM                  NOT NULL DATE          
DATE_TO                    NOT NULL DATE
```

Comment: What does Date_From and Date_To represent? Do you want the latest Date_To value or all the rows where Date_To is "today"? Why do you think a trigger can handle it?... what event will be the triggering event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86d27/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE RESERVATION (
  ID           VARCHAR2(25)  CONSTRAINT RESERVATION__ID__NN NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT RESERVATION__DE__NN NOT NULL,
  DATE_FROM    DATE          CONSTRAINT RESERVATION__DF__NN NOT NULL,
  DATE_TO      DATE          CONSTRAINT RESERVATION__DT__NN NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE TABLE LASTORDERS (
  ID           VARCHAR2(25)  CONSTRAINT LASTORDERS__ID__NN NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT LASTORDERS__DE__NN NOT NULL,
  DATE_FROM    DATE          CONSTRAINT LASTORDERS__DF__NN NOT NULL,
  DATE_TO      DATE          CONSTRAINT LASTORDERS__DT__NN NOT NULL
)
/

CREATE PROCEDURE fulfilReservation(
  I_ID      IN  RESERVATION.ID%TYPE,
  O_SUCCESS OUT NUMBER
)
AS
  r_reservation RESERVATION%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM RESERVATION
  WHERE ID = I_ID
  AND   SYSDATE BETWEEN DATE_FROM AND DATE_TO
  RETURNING ID, DESCRIPTION, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO INTO r_reservation;

  INSERT INTO lastorders VALUES r_reservation;

  o_success := 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    o_success := 0;
END;
/

INSERT INTO RESERVATION VALUES ( 1, 'Test', SYSDATE - 1, SYSDATE + 1 )
/

DECLARE
  success NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  fulfilReservation( 1, success );
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM RESERVATION
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86d27/1/0)**:

```
No Results
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM LASTORDERS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86d27/1/1)**:

```
| ID | DESCRIPTION |                  DATE_FROM |                    DATE_TO |
|----|-------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|  1 |        Test | December, 24 2015 18:59:07 | December, 26 2015 18:59:07 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How to call this procedure automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Trigger can do such job but it will fire only on some changes on table data. If you need to move data between tables in real-time you have to use jobs.

```
    begin
      dbms_scheduler.create_job(
         job_name => 'my_job',
         job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
         enabled => true,
         repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=1',
         start_date => round(sysdate,'DD'),
         job_action => 'begin
           insert into LastOrders
           select * 
             from Reservation 
            where DATE_TO = round(sysdate,''DD'');

           delete Reservation where DATE_TO = round(sysdate,''DD'');       
           commit;
         end;');     
    end;
```

This job will move data from Reservation to LastOrders every day at 00:00.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much and happy new year!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ooo, tricky one!

The main question is how "realtime" you need this to be. You need to consider that data changes on both sides of the equation - meaning, there is new data that enters the table and should be compared to SYSDATE (that's the easy part). The other side is SYSDATE, changing every second. So if you need your data to be as accurate as possible you basically need to check the entire table every second to see if any of the DATE_DO has "arrived" to SYSDATE. This is where the job @Artem suggested comes in handy.

BUT

Running the job once a day means that rows would be moved only once a day, and running it every second would mean querying the table every second (potential performance overhead).

SO, you need to be smart about it -

1. Add an index on DATE_TO
2. Make sure to use bind variables in repeating
   queries you're making on the table. i.e, change the query in the
   job.
3. Build the job in a smart way - Let's say you run it every 5
   min (because you don't want your potentially heavy query to run
   every sec), and you check for the lines that will reach SYSDATE in
   the next 5 min. You can then move to a temporary table that holds
   only these lines, and have another job run on that every second.

Sounds a bit complex, but would save you lot's of trouble if this data is planned to scale.

Good luck, Let me know if you have any questions.